# Can I rescind my agreement to have a recruiter represent me?

Tags: hiring-process

I have been submitted for a position with a recruiter and didn't realize that I could choose any recruiter to represent me.

I also found out that someone was submitted for the same position with a different recruiter that is offering significantly more money and benefits then my recruiter is offering me. I'm not being offered any kind of benefits at all.

Do I have any recourse if I'm chosen for the position?

I would like more money and benefits as I'm very qualified for the position and just interviewed today.

Comment: Not sure why this got a negative reception. It seems to me that the OP is asking something that's considered not done out of simple ignorance of how recruiters work, not out of malice.

Comment: Did you sign a contract?  If not your most likely not obligated to anything.

Comment: @MisterPositive, OP's options for this particular job may be limited though.  Even if OP didn't sign a contract, the recruiter and the hiring firm likely have a contract that states they can only hire OP through this recruiter, since that is who established the connection between OP and employer.

Comment: @cdkMoose That is true.

Comment: @MisterPositive & @ ckdMoose, I have stated in an email that the recruiter can represent me exclusively to the client. I haven't been offered the position or signed any contract yet, so I think I'm obligated to work with this particular recruiter since this makes it legally binding or "right to represent" but just trying to figure out how to get a higher wage because of the cost of living and I will have to purchase health insurance at my own cost.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a **contract** with the recruiter you need to **end** that according to the **conditions** set in it.

*Keep in mind:*

**Recruiters don't offer anything**, they **negotiate on your behalf** and **on your behest** unless you want to negotiate with the prospective employer yourself.

So, if you want more benefits or more money TELL the recruiter that's what you want and they'll reiterate it to the company offering the job.

Comment: @rath ehm.. did you respond to me? I don't see the relation to what I wrote in my answer. I never mentioned anything about mad recruiters...for what it's worth, depending on the amount of recruiters and companies offering work OP is suitable for in the city OP lives in, it might very well be an issue if most of the recruiters know him to be unreliable.hiring companies will hear of this as well...hell hath no fury like a recruiter scorned (;

Comment: Regarding your statement of "Recruiters don't offer anything" I think it depends on the context that the word Recruiter is being used in. If this is a true third party recruiter, who is only involved in the recruitment process and then has no relationship with the client or employee, then yes. But if it's a "recruiter" in the sense of a staffing agency, and the employee is their employee on contract to the client, then they *would* be the ones determining the employee's benefits. I know many "recruiters" who sometimes play either role, depending on the client, so it's not always clear.

Comment: @dwizum in that case, OP probably should clarify. I understood it to be a third party recruiter indeed.

Comment: I think your answer is on point if that's true, and it may be, but I do see a lot of people on here who use "recruiter" in a very broad sense, and the fact that this "recruiter" seems somehow involved in determining benefits made me wonder.

Answer (score 2):

You could also accept the offer at the lower salary, then negotiate for a raise a few months in.

If recruiters' commission in your locale is based on a percentage of the total compensation package, this will leave the recruiter with a sub-optimal outcome now. It might be therefore advisable to work with your recruiter regarding the compensation you feel is reasonable vs. his feeling about it - both are bound to win if you receive a higher offer. But still another consideration to keep in mind is that the recruiter might want to "sell" you at a lower price to increase the chances of you getting the offer, as opposed to someone else with the same qualifications but requesting a higher comp package - because a low offer is better than no offer, for both of you.

Comment: Very true, appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

If you have signed a contract with the recruiter, you should start there to identify options and procedures for terminating the agreement.

For this particular job, you may not have any options.  Third party recruiters often have contracts with employers which state that any candidates they provide can only be hired through that recruiter.  This is to protect the recruiters interests.

Recruiter's offers are not cast in stone, if you don't like what you are being offered for a specific job, then you should be working with the recruiter to get a better offer.  If the recruiter isn't working to get you a better offer, then you should consider moving on with respect to future opportunities.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The recruiter came back with a higher salary amount that I can work with but I think i might request a higher rate sometime in the future, if offered the position.